# Is there a way to parse text as the user is typing an Outlook message?

Tags: outlook

I'd like to write an Outlook add-in that would parse text being typed by the user.
The goal - if the user types a sequence of characters, the add-in would perform some action.

Example: As the user types "@@someone" the add-in would recognize the pattern "\@\@\w{1}" and perform some action.

The problem is I have not found a way to inspect what the user is typing.
Is this restricted? If so, looks like the only option would be to hook into the Send() event and inspect the message then - less ideal.

I'd like to write this add-in in Visual Studio 2010 for Outlook 2010
Any ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is "Smart Tags".  This should provide you a good overview and a direction to go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178786%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here's the SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa169576.aspx

And a basic tutorial: http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-smart-tags.php

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use MailItem.Body?

Also, Application.AcvtiveInspector.WordEditor will return an instance of the Word's Document object that you should be able to access and manipulate the text as the user types it.